# Errors with git alias shell command

Tags: bash, shell-script, git

I'm using bash version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on cygwin with git 1.7.1. I wanted to make an alias for a command that needed to use the input argument twice. Following [these instructions](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced_aliases_with_arguments), I wrote

```
[alias]
branch-excise = !sh -c 'git branch -D $1; git push origin --delete $1' --
```

and I get this error:

```
$> git branch-excise my-branch
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've tried both a `-` and a `--` at the end, but I get the same errors. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `sh` on your system? Why are using `sh` and not `bash` here?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I was following directions from the git manual page that I linked to. Also this stackexchange comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321492/git-alias-with-positional-parameters#comment18892654_3326971 claims that `sh` is more universal across *nixes.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk why in the world would you use bash and not sh there? There's no bashism there, why use a slower, heavier and less portable shell when there's no reason to?

Comment: @terdon: I wouldn't but OP says that he uses and tried `bash` and shows example where `sh` is used

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk ah, fair enough. Many people mistakenly assume that bash == sh, I'm guessing that's what happened here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`man git-config` says:

> The syntax is fairly flexible and permissive; whitespaces are mostly
>   ignored. The # and ; characters begin comments to the end of line,
>   blank lines are ignored.

So:

```
branch-excise = !bash -c 'git branch -D $1; git push origin --delete $1'
```

is an equivalent to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bash -c 'git branch -D $1
```

Running the above script prints:

```
/tmp/quote.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/tmp/quote.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

One solution is to put a whole command in `"`:

```
branch-excise = !"bash -c 'git branch -D $1; git push origin --delete $1'"
```

However, it still doesn't work because `$1` is empty:

```
$ git branch-excise master
fatal: branch name required
fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs
```

In order to make it work you need to create a dummy function in `.gitconfig` and call it like this:

```
branch-excise = ! "ddd () { git branch -D $1; git push origin --delete $1; }; ddd"
```

Usage:

```
$ git branch-excise  master
error: Cannot delete the branch 'master' which you are currently on.
(...)
```

Comment: Worth knowing: unlike a shell, if you accidentally omit the trailing semicolon inside of the `ddd` definition, you also get the same confusing "syntax error: unexpected end of file" error.